# GUi run properly in matlab file but when converted to exe file doesn't work

Tags: matlab, exe

I converted matlab code to exe file with deploytool  this cod use matlab neural network tool box , when I execute the code it returns the next error:

-- error.

```
Default value is not a member of type "nntype.training_fcn".
??? Error using ==> nnetParamInfo>nnetParamInfo.nnetParamInfo at 28
FCN is not the name of a function on the MATLAB path.
error using fitnet>get_info (line 88)
```

Comment: does your .exe deals with Neural networks? and is code of the nn toolbox involved? if that would be the case you can only compile "Pre-trained network command line functions" according to this http://de.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html